# Java Process.waitFor() vs Process.exitValue()

Tags: java, shell, process

Is there a difference between java.lang.Process.waitFor() and exitValue()?

Comment: `exitValue()` throws an exception if the process has not yet terminated. `waitFor()` waits. I got that just by looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exitValue` throws an `IllegalThreadStateException` if the subprocess is not terminated and returns the exit value if its terminated.

`WaitFor` will block the calling thread until the subprocess is terminated and returns immediately if it has already been terminated.

So i would say that they will both behave the same when the subprocess is already terminated but will behave differently when it is still running.
If the subprocess is running , `exitValue` will throw an excpetion and `waitFor` will block the calling thread.

Comment: Hmm exitValue() never throw an IllegalTgreadStateException. Tanks anyway

Comment: @sb27 Process::exitValue could throw an exception if the process is not finished as answered, check the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()